# Azure Kubernetes - PV unable to share with Users?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-files

I have created the File Share using PV & PVC as shown below

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-azurefile
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
EOF


cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-azurefile
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: my-azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
EOF
```

End users should be able to access this file share however I could not configure the Access/IAM

[image]

I need a file share that Kubernetes application uses to upload the files and restricted end users should be able to connect to the file share to download/upload the files. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview)? Azure documents states that before you can enable identity-based authentication on Azure file shares, you must first set up your domain environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction) supports identity-based authentication over Server Message Block (SMB) through two types of Domain Services: on-premises Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) and Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Azure AD DS).

As described in the the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview) before you can enable identity-based authentication on Azure file shares, you must first set up your domain environment.